# What's the difference between clock(), gettickcount(), QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency()?

Tags: windows, clock

Do they all give millisecond resolution?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 12):

No, they don't have millisecond precision. `clock` and `GetTickCount` have between 4 and 15 millisecond precision on most systems. `QueryPerformanceCounter` has a precision in the microsecond to nanosecond range.

`clock` is a wrapper around `GetTickCount` if you're using Microsoft's C runtime library, which, if you're using an MS compiler, you probably are. `GetTickCount` returns a value in milliseconds, but it doesn't increase by one millisecond after one millisecond has elapsed. It is only incremented when a system clock interrupt occurs, which is every four to 15 milliseconds - normally it's about 15ms, but it can be changed by applications. This affects the whole computer: it affects thread scheduling, and the overhead of more frequent interrupts also leaves less CPU time for actually running program code, so don't do it unless you really need it. If your computer is ticking more frequently than 15ms, some other application has modified the tick interrupt frequency.

`QueryPerformanceCounter` uses whatever high-resolution timers are available on the system. In the past, it was usually based on the processor's internal count of clock cycles, so would count at 2-3GHz, or about 0.5ns. Unfortunately some processors varied the rate that the counter would tick at when in low-power states, and in multi-CPU systems (i.e. with multiple processor sockets) you'd get problems if the CPUs weren't all the same speed. Windows now uses other more reliable sources, but they aren't quite as high resolution as the processor. `QueryPerformanceFrequency` tells you how many ticks occur in one second. To get milliseconds, multiply the difference of QPC samples by 1000, and divide by the result of `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Answer (score 3):

**`clock`**

A C++ function. It returns the number of **CPU ticks** since the application is started. To convert this into seconds divide it by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

**`GetTickCount`**

A Win32 API function. Returns the number of **milliseconds** since the system was started.

**`QueryPerformanceCounter`**

A Win32 API function. The performance counter is a high-resolution **counter** which increases over time. To convert this into seconds divide it by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.